# Saving a value without triggering aftersave()

Tags: magento2, api, save

I'm not going in detail about what i'm exactly saving because this question is regards all the possible thing you can save with the ->save() function in each repository.

Anyways , when importing data from an API i use the save() method to store the data that i retrieved. Now it seems that that save() will trigger my plugin AfterSave().

Which makes sense right?

But now is the question. The AfterSave() is ment for when a customer or an admin saves an order/product/customer/... and not for when this is triggered over an autosync (cron job).

Is there somewhere where i can put a filter to determine when to use aftersave and when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the "area" plays a vital role. You can achieve this by carefully adding your plugin in an appropriate area.

Magento 2 has [different areas](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html). For example: frontend, admin, web_api etc. If you want to use your plugin only in frontend, then place your plugin in `frontend` area and thus you can limit the functionality.

ie placing your `di.xml`

> app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\di.xml -- applies everywhere
>   app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml -- applies only for
>   frotend app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml -- applies only
>   for backend side app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\web_api\di.xml --
>   applies only for apis

will have different effects. So always keep "area" scope while you are codding. This is a powerful feature to avoid unnecessary config loadings and hence vital for performance.

Comment: So if i'm right i want to add that to the admin area and the frontend area. And what happends over ssh won't trigger the plugin?

Comment: And by areas you mean put my di.xml in the etc/frontend/ || adminhtml/ folder instead of the etc/ folder.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For custom commands I believe we can set an area as per our need. I am not sure whether there is an "area" for native commands.

Comment: I tried this and it does indeed work great! Thanks , you just reduced my api load by 80% i believe. Big vote up!

Comment: Please see my edit too.

Comment: thanks! I already knew about those but i forgot them for this i guess. Stupid of me. Anyways big thanks!